# Difference between Kotlin-android and kotlin-android-extensions in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions, android-studio-3.0

In android studio 3.0 when we create a new project for kotlin there are two plugins automatically added in app build gradle file like below:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Why do we need to apply the android-extensions plugin in addition with the kotlin-android plugin in android studio? Is there any difference or any reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Every Android developer knows findViewById(). But findViewById is not required with Kotlin anymore.

And how this has happened?  Its because of Kotlin Android Extension.

**how to access TextView with Kotlin :**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    textView.setText("Hello World");   // No need(findViewById) to create a reference variable explicitly
}
```

But how does all this work ?? This is the magic of 'Kotlin Android Extensions'.

You might have noticed below plugin in Gradle file and an import statement in our activity class.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

import statement in Activity:

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
```

Because of this plugin and import statement , we don't explicitly need to create View object in  our activity. we can directly refer View from the name defined in layout file.

If the layout filename is activity_main.xml, we' should

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*.
```

See here for detail :http://kotlin-andro.blogspot.in/2017/07/kotlin-android-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference or any reason behind this

Yes, there is a difference.

The **`kotlin-android-extensions`** plugin is **not** a part of the **`kotlin-android`** plugin. One of the reasons you add the extensions plugin (either explicitly or automatically added for you by Android Studio) is to eliminate having to deal with the *`findViewById`* function because it helps you recover views seamlessly.

Internally the compiler creates a small hidden cache function which calls *`findViewById`* for every view, next time you use the same view it will fetch it from cache instead of calling *`findViewById`* again.

So, you add **`kotlin-android`** to setup Kotlin for Android Studio and [kotlin-android-extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) for eliminate the need for calling *`findViewById`*.

Cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

`kotlin-android` is use for kotlin support and `kotlin-android-extensions` is use for replace findViewById concept of java in android.by using `kotlin-android-extensions`  in your project, you can access directly by Id which you have mentioned in your .xml file like :  android:id="@+id/tvNextAbout" 
 you can use it  in your activity example:

```
tvNextAbout.setOnClickLisnet{}
```

Answer (score -2):

- kotlin-android-plugin is what allows you to use kotlin on Android Studio;
- kotlin-android-extensions provide a set if tools to make android development easier.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html